# Case condition in order clause in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Example stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetOfficeByCountry(IN yr_order tinyint(1))
 BEGIN
 SELECT * 
 FROM offices
 WHERE country LIKE 'A';
 ORDER BY
 CASE yr_order
        WHEN 1 THEN updated
        WHEN 2 THEN likes
        ELSE 1 END  
 ASC
 END //
DELIMITER ;
```

`yr_order` is a stored procedure parameter. The query is fine when the `ASC` is put after the condition:

```
  CASE yr_order
        WHEN 1 THEN updated 
        WHEN 2 THEN likes 
        ELSE 1 END  
  ASC
```

Can I put a different sort order for each condition like this:

```
  CASE yr_order
        WHEN 1 THEN updated ASC
        WHEN 2 THEN likes ASC
        WHEN 3 THEN updated DESC
        WHEN 4 THEN likes DESC
        ELSE 1 END
```

I'm getting a syntax error with that.Is there any way to use different sorting for each condition?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621609/t-sql-conditional-order-by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, but you could do something like:

```
CASE yr_order
        WHEN 1 THEN updated 
        WHEN 2 THEN likes 
        WHEN 3 THEN -updated 
        WHEN 4 THEN -likes 
        ELSE 1 END  
ASC
```

assuming updated and likes are numeric. If they're not, you could do something like:

```
ORDER BY

   CASE yr_order
            WHEN 1 THEN updated 
            WHEN 2 THEN likes 
            ELSE 1 END  
    ASC,
   CASE yr_order

            WHEN 3 THEN updated 
            WHEN 4 THEN likes 
            ELSE 1 END  
    DESC
```