# Generating next primary key value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have two tables. 
The first table is like such

```
ID      Code
NULL    106164029
NULL    106100797
NULL    106100793
NULL    106301098
NULL    106010735
NULL    206010989
NULL    206010956
```

Now the second table is like this...

```
ID  Code
1   102323223
2   105454545
3   106232244
4   106432432
5   106043222
6   206122222
7   211111116
```

How can I generate the next ID (primary key) value for the table when or after I have merged them together so that my table would look like this?

```
ID    Code
1     102323223
2     105454545
3     106232244
4     106432432
5     106043222
6     206122222
7     211111116
8     106164029
9     106100797
10    106100793
11    106301098
12    106010735
13    206010989
14    206010956
```

Comment: will that work with NULL values?

Comment: What have you tried???  Have you tried to just do a simple insert?  It doesn't seem like you tried anything.

Comment: I tried to do an insert... was met with this error: ```Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID, table 'tempdb.dbo.#templist___________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000205A4D'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. ```

Comment: How is the `ID` value in your second table generated? Is it an `IDENTITY` column? Or the `NEXT VALUE FOR` a `SEQUENCE` object? Where that comes from makes all the difference.

Comment: The 3rd table - is it a separate table, or you just add data from first to second? Does it have `identity` already? Which SQL Server version you use, does it allow to use sequences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `IDENTITY` property for you PK field and can keep the order of the first table, and the give a random order to the second.

You could also specify an order for the table with the `NULL` id's, but you'd have to choose what that order is with a [conditional order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621609/t-sql-conditional-order-by) since the table has no logical order based on what you have provided.

```
create table #t1 (id int null, code bigint)
create table #t2 (id int null, code bigint)

insert into #t1
values
(NULL,106164029),
(NULL,106100797),
(NULL,106100793),
(NULL,106301098),
(NULL,106010735),
(NULL,206010989),
(NULL,206010956)

insert into #t2
values
(1,102323223),
(2,105454545),
(3,106232244),
(4,106432432),
(5,106043222),
(6,206122222),
(7,211111116)

--here is your final table with the auto calculated id primary key
create table #t3 (id int identity (1,1), code bigint)
alter table #t3 add constraint pk primary key (id)

--the order by keeps the same order as the original table with the id values
insert into #t3
select code from #t2
order by id

--since the ID is null in this table, i didn't specify an order by but you could using conditional order by
insert into #t3
select code from #t1


--see the results
select * from #t3 order by id

drop table #t1, #t2, #t3
```

This returns the following, which has your order for the first table (1-7) but no guaranteed order for the second unless you apply some logic to specify the order of that table. As it is, there is no way to tell. A single clustered index could help.

```
+----+-----------+
| id |   code    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | 102323223 |
|  2 | 105454545 |
|  3 | 106232244 |
|  4 | 106432432 |
|  5 | 106043222 |
|  6 | 206122222 |
|  7 | 211111116 |
|  8 | 106164029 |
|  9 | 106100797 |
| 10 | 106100793 |
| 11 | 106301098 |
| 12 | 106010735 |
| 13 | 206010989 |
| 14 | 206010956 |
+----+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. Turns out it was this but I did not need to specify (1,1) or the alter table command

Comment: The table creations were to just add the sample data

Answer (score 0):

You have three ways.

The first (simple) way: define an identity field, so it fill itself when you execute an `INSERT` statement.

The second way: When you write your INSERT statement you can apply a logic to calculate your ID, as follow:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (id, code)
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable t2
       WHERE t2.code < @code), 0), code
```

The third way: You apply an `UPDATE` statement after your `INSERT`.

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (code) VALUES (yourcode)
```

and after all INSERT statements you can write as follow:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET id = 
    ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable t2
    WHERE t2.code < yourtable.code), 0)
WHERE id IS NULL
```

Comment: They want to maintain the order of their data (though one table has no real order) so for the table that has the ID field populated, an `order by` on insert to your identity column would do this.

Comment: Jeff Moden will try to kill you if he will happen across your third query. This is a semi-cartesian, it will bring the server to its knees on any reasonable amount of data.

Comment: @scsimon: The order will affect the new data (but in question are the same order of table1)

Comment: @RogerWolf: Yes Roger, but I only describe all possible solution