# Grouping by a column and selecting first record in group after sorting and ordering dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For a simple and hardcoded scenario, it works

Looks like I am making some mistake syntactically when sorting and ordering dynamically with multiple columns.

I get the error, incorrect syntax near the comma after Nbr **,**
I also get this error, incorrect syntax near 'ELSE'

```
DECLARE @OrderBy varchar(50) = 'ArrivalDate'
DECLARE @OrderDirection smallint = 1

--grouping by Nbr and selecting the first record in the group after sorting and ordering

--Issues with dynamic sorting and ordering
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by Nbr 
                                      ORDER BY 
                                        CASE WHEN @OrderDirection = 1 THEN
                                           CASE WHEN Lower(@OrderBy) = 'arrivaldate' THEN Nbr, ArrivalDate,
                                           CASE WHEN Lower(@OrderBy) = 'status' THEN Nbr, EnrolmentStatus,
                                           ELSE Nbr
                                        END ASC,                                                                    
                                        CASE WHEN @OrderDirection <> 1 THEN
                                           CASE WHEN Lower(@OrderBy) = 'arrivaldate' THEN Nbr, ArrivalDate,
                                           CASE WHEN Lower(@OrderBy) = 'status' THEN Nbr, EnrolmentStatus                                                                       
                                           ELSE Nbr
                                        END DESC;
                                   ) as row_number
       FROM #TempResults
) as rows
where row_number = 1
```

I have quickly created a script to play with some data

```
CREATE TABLE #TempResults
(
  Nbr int,  
  StudentName varchar(50) null, 
  EnrolmentStatus char(1), 
  ArrivalDate datetime, 
  TransportMode char(1) 
)

SELECT * FROM #TempResults
INSERT INTO #TempResults (Nbr,  StudentName, EnrolmentStatus, ArrivalDate,TransportMode)
VALUES 
(1, 'ABC-1', 'A', '2021-04-12', 'X'),
(2, 'ABC-1', 'B', '2021-04-12', 'X'),
(3, 'ABC-1', 'A', '2021-04-11', 'Y'),
(4, 'ABC-1', 'A', '2021-04-11', 'Z'),
(5, 'ABC-1', 'A', '2021-04-10', 'X'),
(6, 'ABC-1', 'B', '2021-04-11', 'X'),
(7, 'ABC-1', 'A', '2021-04-11', 'Y'),
(8, 'ABC-1', 'A', '2021-04-08', 'Z'),
(1, 'ABC-2', 'A', '2021-04-12', 'X'),
(2, 'ABC-2', 'B', '2021-04-12', 'X'),
(3, 'ABC-2', 'A', '2021-04-11', 'Y'),
(4, 'ABC-2', 'A', '2021-04-11', 'Z'),
(5, 'ABC-2', 'A', '2021-04-10', 'X'),
(6, 'ABC-2', 'B', '2021-04-11', 'X'),
(7, 'ABC-2', 'A', '2021-04-11', 'Y'),
(8, 'ABC-2', 'A', '2021-04-08', 'Z'),
(1, 'ABC-3', 'A', '2021-04-12', 'X'),
(2, 'ABC-3', 'B', '2021-04-12', 'X'),
(3, 'ABC-3', 'A', '2021-04-11', 'Y'),
(4, 'ABC-3', 'A', '2021-04-11', 'Z'),
(5, 'ABC-3', 'A', '2021-04-10', 'X'),
(6, 'ABC-3', 'B', '2021-04-11', 'X'),
(7, 'ABC-3', 'A', '2021-04-11', 'Y'),
(8, 'ABC-3', 'A', '2021-04-08', 'Z'),
(1, 'ABC-3', 'A', '2021-04-12', 'X'),
(2, 'ABC-3', 'B', '2021-04-12', 'X'),
(3, 'ABC-3', 'A', '2021-04-11', 'Y'),
(4, 'ABC-3', 'A', '2021-04-11', 'Z'),
(5, 'ABC-3', 'A', '2021-04-10', 'X'),
(6, 'ABC-3', 'B', '2021-04-11', 'X'),
(7, 'ABC-3', 'A', '2021-04-11', 'Y'),
(8, 'ABC-3', 'A', '2021-03-08', 'Z'),
(4, 'ABC-5', 'A', '2021-04-11', 'Z'),
(5, 'ABC-5', 'A', '2021-03-10', 'X'),
(6, 'ABC-5', 'B', '2021-03-11', 'X'),
(7, 'ABC-5', 'A', '2021-03-11', 'Y'),
(8, 'ABC-5', 'A', '2021-03-08', 'Z'),
(1, 'ABC-5', 'A', '2021-04-12', 'X'),
(2, 'ABC-5', 'B', '2021-04-12', 'X'),
(3, 'ABC-5', 'A', '2021-03-11', 'Y'),
(4, 'ABC-5', 'A', '2021-03-11', 'Z'),
(6, 'ABC-6', 'B', '2021-03-11', 'X'),
(7, 'ABC-6', 'A', '2021-03-11', 'Y'),
(8, 'ABC-6', 'A', '2021-03-08', 'Z'),
(1, 'ABC-6', 'A', '2021-03-12', 'X'),
(2, 'ABC-6', 'B', '2021-04-01', 'X'),
(3, 'ABC-6', 'A', '2021-04-02', 'Y'),
(4, 'ABC-6', 'A', '2021-04-03', 'Z'),
(5, 'ABC-6', 'A', '2021-04-07', 'X')
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Lower(@OrderBy) = 'ArrivalDate'` ? it doesn't make sense

Comment: Legacy script, probably case sensitive - hence Lower used, I guess

Comment: then shouldn't it be comparing it with a lower case string ? `Lower(@OrderBy) = 'arrivaldate'`. By the way, you have not explain what is the problem with your existing query. Please include some sample data and the expected result

Comment: Sample data + expected results will go a long way to clarifying your question.

Comment: I have edited the question, I get the error, incorrect syntax near the comma after Nbr in the CASE expression, I also get this error, incorrect syntax near 'ELSE' and also Incorrect syntax near 'END'. Expecting ')', EXCEPT or UNION.

Comment: A similar [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621609/t-sql-conditional-order-by).

Comment: You have commas in your `CASE`  expression @InquisitiveLad . You need to read the errors... They normally tell you the problem.

Comment: You can't use `case` in that fashion, it must return a single value `then value, value` is not valid. Possibly you could try repeating the expression for each sort order value? Looks like as per above link `dsql` would be the better option though.

Comment: I was following this link https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/06/08/sql-server-how-to-order-by-a-parameter/

Comment: That article doesn't have commas (`,`) after each returned scalar value, @InquisitiveLad , nor multiple values in  an `ELSE`. Personally, I would recommend having the application worrying about the ordering if you want the user to be able to ad-hoc choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few issues noted with your query

Your case expression syntax is wrong. You have missing `END` and extra comma here and there. Please refer to documentation on [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for the proper syntax

> ```
> CASE input_expression   
>      WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ]   
>      [ ELSE else_result_expression ]   
> END
> ```

`CASE` is an expression and not a statement. An expression returns a single value. You had multiple column inside your `CASE`

Another point is all return path of the `CASE` expression must have the same data type. You have `ArrivalDate` - `datetime` and `EnrolmentStatus` - `varchar`. The following query, i have convert the `datetime` to `varchar`

Your `row_number()` query should be

```
 row_number() over 
 (
     PARTITION BY Nbr 
     ORDER BY 
         CASE WHEN @OrderDirection = 1 THEN
              CASE WHEN Lower(@OrderBy) = 'arrivaldate' THEN convert(varchar(10), ArrivalDate, 121)
                   WHEN Lower(@OrderBy) = 'status'      THEN EnrolmentStatus
              END 
         END ASC,
         CASE WHEN @OrderDirection <> 1 THEN
              CASE WHEN Lower(@OrderBy) = 'arrivaldate' THEN convert(varchar(10), ArrivalDate, 121)
                   WHEN Lower(@OrderBy) = 'status'      THEN EnrolmentStatus 
              END 
         END DESC
 ) as row_no
```

And I change the alias to `row_no` instead of `row_number` which is a keyword in `SQL Server`.

Answer (score 2):

Handling "dynamic" `ORDER BY` clauses is tricky.  The issue is that `CASE` is an *expression* that returns only a single value -- and the type is determined during compile time.

I recommend writing a separate `CASE` expression for each condition:

```
ORDER BY nbr,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Nbr 
                            ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @OrderDirection = 1 AND Lower(@OrderBy) = 'arrivaldate' THEN ArrivalDate END),
                                     (CASE WHEN @OrderDirection = 1 AND Lower(@OrderBy) = 'status' THEN EnrolmentStatus END),
                                     (CASE WHEN @OrderDirection <> 1 AND Lower(@OrderBy) = 'arrivaldate' THEN ArrivalDate END) DESC,
                                     (CASE WHEN @OrderDirection <> 1 AND Lower(@OrderBy) = 'status' THEN EnrolmentStatus END) DESC
                           ) as row_number
```

This is a bit more verbose but you don't have to worry about type conversion between different column types.