Any way to add a falsey `ORDER BY`?
I often add in a falsey predicate for convenience in debugging, like this:
SELECT ...
WHERE 1=1
    AND/OR predicate1
    AND/OR predicate2
    ...etc

This way I can comment out one or more lines and my query will still work. Is there a way to do the equivalent of 1=1 for an ORDER BY? For example, filling in the ?? in the following:
SELECT ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ???,
   sort1,
   sort2, 
   ...

I believe almost all mainstream db engines will optimize out 1=1, but I wonder if it does the same for an ORDER BY that is intentionally falsey?

no they take the condition as true and use it

maybe conditionally sorting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621609/t-sql-conditional-order-by

@nbk sorry I don't follow, could you please explain what you mean by 'take the condition as true' ?

Order by a constant, and use leading commas for your optional other sorts:
ORDER BY 'x'
   , sort1
   , sort2


Thinking the same thing. Any constant scalar will do as the first ordering term.
